# Changing 'IF and NULL' from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have problem in changing the query from MySQL to SQL Server. I tried to change it to `ISNULL` and `IIF` in SQL but still doesn't work. Any tips or help are welcome, thanks!

**Question 1 :**

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT i.item_name
         , r.item_version
         , SUM(IF(r.group_status=1,r.quantity,0)) AS `Approved`
         , SUM(IF(r.group_status=2,r.quantity,0)) AS `NotApproved`
         , SUM(r.quantity)                        AS `Total`
      FROM requesters r
      JOIN items i
        ON i.item_id = r.item_id
     WHERE r.group_status IN (1,2)
       AND r.requested_date >= '$a'
       AND r.requested_date <= '$b'
     GROUP
        BY i.item_name
         , r.item_version
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT i.item_name
     , r.item_version
     , SUM(ISNULL(r.group_status=1,r.quantity,0)) AS `Approved`
     , SUM(ISNULL(r.group_status=2,r.quantity,0)) AS `NotApproved`
     , SUM(r.quantity)                        AS `Total`
  FROM requesters r
  JOIN items i
    ON i.item_id = r.item_id
 WHERE r.group_status IN (1,2)
   AND r.requested_date >= '$a'
   AND r.requested_date <= '$b'
 GROUP
    BY i.item_name
     , r.item_version
```

It keep saying `Incorrect syntax near ','` and still doesn't work.

**Question 2 :**

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IF(endusers.price,endusers.price,0)),0) AS `totalprice` 
FROM endusers
WHERE requester_code = '$req_code'
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT NULLIF(SUM(COALESCE(endusers.price,endusers.price,0)),0) AS 'totalprice' 
FROM endusers 
WHERE requester_code = '$req_code'
```

The problem when I use `COALESCE` in Question 2, it won't display `'0'` when there's no value in the table.

Comment: Don't use backquotes in SQLServer

Comment: @festvender In first query I think you need to sum with 2different set of data and in second query you sum with check that if does not have value return 0. Right? if yes, why you use **coalesce**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isnull` function in SQL Server is not equivalent of `if` function in MySQL, use `case` operator instead:

```
SUM(case when r.group_status=1 then r.quantity else 0 end))
```

In the second case it looks like you're using `coalesce` incorrectly too since it just takes first not-null value from arguments, and it is not equivalent of MySQL `if` function, use `case` operator too.

Also in the second case you will not get `0` value when there is not result - at least because you have wrapped it with `nullif` and it outputs `null` when resulting sum is 0. So this part of your question really needs to be clarified, probably with source data sample and desired output.

Comment: Ive change it and how to solve the 'Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.' came out?

Comment: @festvender change the data type from text to numerical :                                      sum(cast(varchar column as int)) - Or as whatever numerical datatype you want

Comment: Well, if you're getting such an errors - it means your `r.quantity` value has been stored as `varchar` data type in DB. If it is intended - then just use `cast(r.quantity as int)` instead of `r.quantity`. But generally storing numerics as `varchar` should be avoided.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Its work but still not stable I think, Do you mind to take a look at it ? http://pastebin.com/g636EMJ2 , If there any wrong regarding that query please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see, you're still using `r.quantity` in conditional sums with `case` operator and casting it to `int` only in `Total` column. You have to cast it to int in every place you're using `sum`. Or, as I've already said - just change DB column type from varchar to int.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Noted, so other than that, there is no problem right? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, the issues are

1. You can not give single quote(`) with column as given with`Approved` column
2. Your isnull condition is wrong isnull (columnname , TexttoReplace)

   ```
     SELECT i.item_name
    , r.item_version
    , SUM(ISNULL(r.group_status, 1))  AS Approved
    , SUM(ISNULL(r.group_status,2)) AS NotApproved
    , SUM(r.quantity)  AS Total
   FROM requesters r
   JOIN items i
     ON i.item_id = r.item_id
   WHERE r.group_status IN (1,2)
   AND r.requested_date >= '$a'
   AND r.requested_date <= '$b'
   GROUP
   BY i.item_name
    , r.item_version
   ```

Second query is not clearly understand. give the data with.

Comment: About the second, please look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/479fb/1, Ive have problem when there are decimal number.

Comment: @festvender in your sample you're having your `price` column type as `varchar`, but actually storing `decimal` values in it. Is there any reason for it? Anyway, if you cant' change your DB structure and it forces you to use `varchar` for the price - then change `COALESCE(endusers.price,0)` to `COALESCE(cast(endusers.price as decimal(10, 2)),0)`.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev what other data type that suitable in my case if I want to change the DB structure?. `(Ex: 200.97)`

Comment: float or numeric(18,2)

Comment: @festvender i wouldn't recommend to use `float` data type for financial calculations since it is "approximate" type. Use `decimal(x,y)` where `x` is maximum size of your numbers and `y` is precision. In your particular case it is somthing like `decimal(10, 2)` or similar.

Comment: @Ajay2707 Thanks for ur sugesstion

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I faced one more problem, the query shows `NULL` instead of `0` if there is no value in DB. What I need to change in order to display `NULL` to `0`?. Please take a look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1042a4/2

Comment: @festvender well, I've mentioned this previously in my answer. Using `nullif` function here will not lead you to the result you're expecting (it is quite opposite function to the one you need). Instead in this particular case you should use `isnull`, and the query should be `select isnull(sum(coalesce(endusers.price,0)), 0) AS 'totalprice' `

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thank you!